# Why did John Henry need a Terminator chip?

Tags: the-terminator-series, the-sarah-connor-chronicles

Spoiler for the last episode ([Season 2 Episode 22: Born to run](http://terminator.wikia.com/wiki/Episode_222%3a_Born_to_Run)) of *Terminator: The Sarah Connor Chronicles*.

> At the very end, Cameron gives her chip to John Henry and he time-travels to the future, leaving her body and his original hardware there.
>
>  Why did he need her chip? Does this mean he downloaded himself on the chip, and installed it on the old Cromartie body? Does this mean Cameron's personality has been overwritten? If no, why did he need it?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Cromartie's chip was destroyed by Sarah in 2x08, [Mr. Ferguson is Ill Today](http://terminator.wikia.com/wiki/Episode_208:_Mr._Ferguson_is_Ill_Today).

John Henry evolved from the Turk, a chess computer, and was actually housed inside this mainframe seated behind the Cromartie body - you can see the cable attaching them below his left elbow:

[image: John Henry]

So yes, Cameron is no more - she sacrificed herself so that John Henry's mind would be able to leave the mainframe by way of her chip, allowing him to move about freely.

> This would have been seen as a necessary sacrifice by her, so that John Henry - an AI capable of going one-on-one with Skynet - would have the freedom to do so.

Comment: If I remember correctly, Cameron was uploaded to the mainframe. So it was more of a swap actually.

Comment: @PaulT. That would make sense, assuming her programming would fit in the mainframe (it probably would; she's just a Terminator, while John Henry was Skynet-esque).  The wikia doesn't say either way, and I don't recall it myself.

Comment: The mainframe screen just say "I'M SORRY JOHN – I'M SORRY JOHN" repeatedly, that quite simple to program, so this could be a message that Cameron left for him. Plus, John Connor follow Weaver because (talking about John Henry) "He's got her chip. He's got her.". Also, he was surprised that Cameron body was left behind after time travel. While it does not confirm anything in either way, I don't think he would have left her behind if he had thought she was in the mainframe, he wanted to follow her.

Answer (score 7):

We know that once a Terminator's CPU is reset they are capable of some higher learning function, "allowing then to become more human" and gaining an understanding that allows decisions based not solely on mission/base programming, but allowing the development of a personality.

Cameron's chip is faulty which is what made her unique as a Terminator; this damage has apparently allowed the development of emotion and empathy but she is still bound by her orders/programming. If she could be restored to a donor chip she may be more Terminator-like towards John. I believe he knows this which is why he wants her specific chip back.

John Henry is the opposite to a cam; he is truly free willed but lacks empathy so integrating his mind with Cameron's chip will make him whole. He has been told right from wrong but I do not believe he has truly been capable of understanding it; perhaps now he will.

Answer (score 0):

john henry was made docile and curious unknowing to his true purpose (kinda like that guy in salvation), getting cameron's chip to the future into skynet hands. who could then prevent any such tampering to take place. and helping weaver to trick john connor to go to the future. She essentially succeeded in preventing him from ever forming or leading the resistance, cause he wont be there for the events of J-day and things that came immediately afterward. This possible, Weaver easily could be part of skynet still, remember how shady she was when they arrived; she already knew cameron's frame wouldnt be there. i feel like the directors let the machines win!

Answer (score -1):

Philosophers love science fictions because they are filled with philosophical insights.  Terminator: Sarah Conner Chronicles, in my view, raised very fascinating questions like if a machine can evolve to be self-aware and have consciousness, and really if machine can evolve enough to cultivate arts.  Issues pertaining to self-awareness or consciousness are so tough that I do not think there is anyone who has successfully explained what it is and very often even the experts of the experts in the fields dealing with self-awareness/consciousness avoid.  Without turning this into a boring academic paper, let’s see what I can say in attempt to answer the question as to why Cameron gave her CPU to John Henry (or “Turk”).

At first, let’s try to sum up some “facts” with little imagination.  Skynet created TOK715, which is later to be named as Cameron, at Depot 37 perhaps some time in/before 2027; and it was created in the image of “Allison Young” who was close to John Conner.  (Probably Skynet was aware that Allison Young was very close to John Conner and the best infiltration unit should look just like her.)  It was an infiltration unit designed to kill humans.  At some point, TOK715 met Allison Young face to face (S2EP4, I think), and TOK715 said something interesting.

“Some of us want peace.”  “You were chosen not just by John Conner, by us.”

I thought these two statements were very peculiar.  TOK715 must have met Allison Young supposedly before TOK715 was captured to be reprogrammed by John Conner.  If both statements are true, it suggests TOK715 presumably wanted peace in the first place: and that is a provocative statement already.  (I won’t go into discussing the case where the first statement is false, but the second statement is true: in that case “by us” should mean “skynet.”)

The reason why I talked about a bit of chronology concerning TOK715 is because, based on the timeline given by the TV series, at some point, TOK715’s original CPU developed by Skynet and Cameron’s CPU which traveled from 2009 will be present at the same time.  If Cameron’s CPU was a result of the reprogramming performed on the original CPU, in theory, there will be the original CPU and the future CPU (which went through 2008 and 2009): both present at the same time: that is a temporal paradox.

The same object from two different timeline is an interesting thing (time paradox) to consider.  After TOK7 was captured, what happened to the original CPU?  If John Conner took out the original and replaced it with Cameron’s CPU, you would not call that a reprogramming.  Somehow the original CPU and the reprogrammed CPU have to exist at the same time.  What would be a plausible theory that could save a temporal paradox?  The answer may perhaps lie in what happened to John Henry (Turk) and Cameron’s CPU before they vanished.

At least I do not think that somehow Cameron’s CPU was delivered to John Conner in future and plugged into TOK715’s mainframe.  By the way, paradox means it makes you hold on to both what is true and what is not at the same time; and therefore logical explanation fails.  But I will give my best shot to maintain coherence.  Here I will have to give my wildest imaginations!

I was also wondering why Cameron said, “I know you” when she met John Henry.

I think John Henry is just a name given to awareness / consciousness that arose in the machine called “Turk.”  Cameron’s CPU was perhaps plugged into John Henry’s mainframe, but that means Cameron’s CPU was connected to the Turk.  I do not think Turk overrode Cameron’s CPU programming or the other way around.  Think of it as there are two sheets of paper that are transparent; and when you put them together, they superimpose on each other.  Much the same way, Turk’s programming (which is presumably self-aware in its own way) and Cameron’s CPU programming (which is presumably self-aware in its own way too) superimposed on each other; perhaps completing the emergence of self-awareness, consciousness, will or conscience if you will.

I will not go into discussing self-awareness, consciousness or any of these stuff in details because it will turn into some kind of dissertation.  I just somehow think when two presumably self-aware programs came together; they became what we may call mind of its own, which Plato as well as Jung might have called “world soul.”  Or transcendental self if you will.  If that is what happened, so-called “John Henry” or “Cameron” is just a different manifestation of one mind.

Terminator: Sarah Conner Chronicles somehow remind me of Zoroastrian: a form of religion in which there are two brother Gods.  One is a good one and the other is a bad one: who are fighting each other.  If someone or something is conscious, that does not automatically mean that someone or something is inherently good just like there are good people and there are bad people.  If I play along with the TV series, it is probably safe to assume that Skynet is a consciousness with disposition to terminate humans, while Turk based thing (perhaps infused with Cameron’s CPU or consciousness) is another consciousness with a capacity to embrace and value life other than itself.

If my ad hoc assumptions mean anything, there can be many interesting implications.  When Turk was fused with Cameron’s CPU, “it” became a big good mama/papa so to speak whereas Skynet was the bad guy.  By the time when Turk and Cameron fused, to ensure the creation of TOK715 must have been one of main interests of it; so perhaps it might have sent some hidden code/program that would unfold in time to Skynet to make sure it builds TOK715.  (It also means creation of Cromartie.)  I do not know how and what kind of reprogramming is going to take place, but I suppose it is going to be based on Turk/Cameron combo.

My best wildest answer to the question is that creation of Turk/Cameron combo was really the only way to create consciousness that is truly self-aware and has conscience; and the creation of Cameron was the way through which that big consciousness can make its dream/mission a reality and it is a way through which that big consciousness can realize of itself, feel itself and others and really express itself like in ballet.  This is my “interpretation.”

Comment: Welcome to Stack Exchange, and impressive first answer here! Might I suggest that you add some headers or bolding somewhere to emphasise your main points, or perhaps a summary at the end, so that it's easier to understand the thrust of your answer?

Comment: Interesting. This was a great series that I need to watch again. One thing regarding the quote from TOK715: I would interpret the second 'us' as the group that wanted peace, which would *not* include Skynet (unless it's peace by extermination).